# How does the Adjacency List Relationships works in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am reading the [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) docs and get confused by the given example:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node")
```

I know a Node object can have many children by this class definition. My understanding is when creating and saving a Node object, a record (id, parent_id, data) will be inserted into the database, I know `id` will be generated by default, but how is the `parent_id` generated? I tried a similiar usage in my project, but the `parent_id` stays `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent_id` is not really generated, it is assigned using the actual **relationships** between objects. This is to say that `sqlalchemy` will save proper the `parent_id` to all the children the relationship `Node.children`.

For example, in order to achieve the relationship graph as documented in the `sqlalchemy`'s documentation you link to:

```
root --+---> child1
       +---> child2 --+--> subchild1
       |              +--> subchild2
       +---> child3
```

you may write a code in the following way:

```
root = Node(
    data='root',
    # @NOTE: all Node under this children will have `parent_id` point to the `id` of this (root) Node
    children=[
        Node(data='child1'),
        Node(data='child2',
             children=[
                 Node(data='subchild1'),
                 Node(data='subchild2'),
             ]),
        Node(data='child3')
    ]
)

session.add(root)  # this will also add all the other nodes in the graph
session.commit()
```